# Show an element according to user type in CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.6

I would like some guidance and advice on my problem:

I am using Cakephp framework to develop a web based system. For this system I have 3 type of users: Admin, Staff and Editor.  I would like to have an element which will show when any user will be logged in. Moreover, I would like that the content on this element will be different for each type of user.

Moreover if a website visitor visits the website (not logged in) I would like to have the element hidden.

I created 3 elements... for now with some text in each... However I do not know how to proceed...

**I appreciate your guidance and advice :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using auth component this piece of code will help

```
if (AuthComponent::user("id")) { 
  //AuthComponent::loggedIn() you can use this as well.
  if (AuthComponent::user("role_id") == ADMIN) {
    echo $this->element('admin/menu');
  } elseif (AuthComponent::user("role_id") == STAFF) {
    echo $this->element('staff/menu');
  } elseif (AuthComponent::user("role_id") == EDITOR) {
    echo $this->element('editor/menu');
  }
}
```

OR you can read the value from the session and compare if you are using your custom method for login.

Comment: in layout or if you want you can place it in view file or controller as well. my opinion is layout.

Comment: Franky!!!! Thanks a lot you where very helpful.  I managed thanks to your help! Thank you!